# How do I redirect after saving the user account with $user->save()?

Tags: 8, users, redirection

How can I redirect users in a custom module after saving a user account with `$user->save()`? It always goes to the user profile after saving and I want to redirect to a custom page.

```
function user_update_redirect(&$form, $form_state) {
  $value1 = $form_state->getValue('panel');
  $value2 = $form_state->getValue('type_of_user');
  $storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
  $user = user_load($user->id());
  $user->set('field_panel', $value1);
  $user->set('field_type_of_user', $value2);
  kint($user);
  $user->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to remain on your site when redirecting.
I don't recommend hardcoded URL's anywhere else but in route.yml files.
Call the right service and don't forget to use dependency injection in your services and don't use a trait or directly call it from the container.

```
  private function redirect(string $route) {
    $path = $this->container->get('url_generator')->getPathFromRoute($route);
    return new RedirectResponse($path);
  }
```

Comment: The OP is showing the code of a form submission handler. It's not clear how a form submission could use the code shown here.

Comment: Well OP's code snippet does not tell much what the context is. 
So it's hard to tell how he should exactly use this.

Comment: `user_update_redirect(&$form, $form_state)` could be either a form submission or a form validation handler. Given the OP is saving a user account inside it, it's probable it's a form submission handler. In any case, using `$form_state` it's possible to redirect the users without creating any redirect response.

Answer (score 2):

```
$form_state->setRedirectUrl(Url::fromUserInput($redirect_path));
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answer! Thank you for your answer. Please try to elaborate it a bit. Why this snippet, how to use it, in what function, what is `$redirect_path`? One-line answers don't provide that much of a value for future readers. Thanks! And keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

After `$user->save();` add

```
  $url = Url::fromRoute('route.name');
  $response = new RedirectResponse($url->toString());
  // $response = '/some/path';
  $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($response);
  $response->send();
```

Comment: You don't want to be sending your own response in the middle of form processing - unpredictable things can happen

Answer (score 0):

In `user_update_redirect()`, which gets a [`FormState`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/class/FormState/8.7.x) object, you can call one of the following methods.

- [`FormState::setRedirect()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirect/8.7.x)
- [`FormState::setRedirectUrl()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirectUrl/8.7.x)

`FormState::setRedirect()` is preferable when the redirecting URL is associated with a route, such as in the case of nodes, user accounts, or other entities. In the other cases, such as redirecting to external URLs, `FormState::setRedirectUrl()` is the method to use.

Returning a [`RedirectResponse`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21RedirectResponse.php/class/RedirectResponse/8.7.x) object in a form submission handler doesn't have any effect. The method calling ([`FormSubmitter::executeSubmitHandlers`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormSubmitter.php/function/FormSubmitter%3A%3AexecuteSubmitHandlers/8.7.x)) the form submission handlers discard the value returned from them.

```
  $handlers = $form_state->getSubmitHandlers();

  // Otherwise, check for a form-level handler.
  if (!$handlers && !empty($form['#submit'])) {
    $handlers = $form['#submit'];
  }
  foreach ($handlers as $callback) {

    // Check if a previous _submit handler has set a batch, but make sure we
    // do not react to a batch that is already being processed (for instance
    // if a batch operation performs a
    //  \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface::submitForm()).
    if (($batch =& $this->batchGet()) && !isset($batch['id'])) {

      // Some previous submit handler has set a batch. To ensure correct
      // execution order, store the call in a special 'control' batch set.
      // See _batch_next_set().
      $batch['sets'][] = [
        'form_submit' => $callback,
      ];
      $batch['has_form_submits'] = TRUE;
    }
    else {
      call_user_func_array($form_state->prepareCallback($callback), [
        &$form,
        &$form_state,
      ]);
    }
  }
```

Calling `RedirectResponse::send()` from a from submission handler would just interrupt what Drupal is doing when processing a form, including calling other form submission handlers and other hooks.

In the case there is the need to use `FormState::setRedirectUrl()`, the `Url` object should be built from [`Url::fromUserInput()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUserInput/8.7.x) only when the relative URI was given by user input (for example, when users fill a setting form for giving a redirect path). For an external URL well known from the module implementing the form submission handler, [`Url::fromUri()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.7.x) should be used.